# Override property in baseClass with implementation of its interface c#

Tags: c#

Is it possible to override a property in a BaseClass somehow. What I'm trying to do is below. Perhaps I should just use another propertyname in the subclasses.

```
  public interface IRow
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public class MySpecificRow : IRow
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SomethingSpecific { get; set; }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    protected IRow Row;

    public BaseClass(IRow row)
    {
        Row = row;
    }
}

public class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    public SubClass(IRow row) : base(row) { }
    private MySpecificRow Row { get { return (MySpecificRow) base.Row; } }
}
```

The last row throws the error that i hides the base class Row property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question, I believe you can use the "new" keyword. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx

That said, this is usually not a good idea. I don't know whether your code is just a simplified example, or whether you have additional constraints.

Comment: Yes, the code is a simplified example. I do want to hide the base class property since the Interface only exposes a few properties. Why is this usually not a good idea?